# Spring sf form tags how to change type?

Tags: forms, spring

This gives me error prone HTML code, because Spring automatically generates text type, how do I change this behaviour?

```
<td><sf:input type="password" path="password" size="20" maxlength="30" /><br /> 
<sf:errors path="password"cssClass="error" />
</td>
```

html code generated:

```
… name="password" **type="password" type="text"** value="" size="20" maxlength="30" …
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **the password** tag

This tag renders an HTML 'input' tag with type 'password'

```
<form:password path="password" />
```

For details

[The password tag](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/view.html)

Comment: Thanks, link is useful too! I also realize that this tag finally gives me needed behavior: when putting   mav.getModel().putAll(bindingResult.getModel()); before it also gave back previously entered password to a user, but now it seems that password is never returned if it is wrong, which is what I wanted, not sure though why.

Comment: You are welcomed.You are right.But i know a simple trick in client side.In a password field password is present but not seen.If you use firebug then inspect the password field and if you make that type="text" in the browser with the help of firebug then you can see it. ;-)

Comment: I wonder why it is to common forcing re-entering valid passwords if some other values in the form are wrong. If say address wrong we save previously entered valid name, this is not the case with password .